# select elements from a list by 0 or 1

Tags: functions

I have the following two lists $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{0,1,0\}$. Now based on the value of $B$ I want to select the value of $A$ and store in a new list. If $0$ then it will not select the value, if $1$ it will select the value. So, the new list will contain $C=\{b\}$. I do not have idea how to do in mathematica

Answer (score 12):

Use Pick

```
Pick[{a,b,c},{0,1,0},1]
```

Comment: +1, the canonical and generally most efficient method.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method to `Pick`:

**Extract/Position**

```
Extract[{a,b,c},Position[{0,1,0},1]]

(* {b} *)
```

In addition, and in the spirit of @Nasser:

**PositionIndex/Part**

```
{a,b,c,d}[[PositionIndex[{1,0,1,0}][1]]]

(* {a, c} *)
```

**Cases/Transpose**

```
Cases[Transpose[{A,B}],{x_,1}:>x]

(* {b} *)

Cases[Transpose[{{a,b,c,d},{1,0,1,0}}],{x_,1}:>f[x]]

(* {f[a], f[c]} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to multiply the two lists then remove all the zeros:

```
list1 = {a, b, c}; list2 = {0, 1, 0};
Select[list1 list2, # =!= 0 &]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun and to also get to 10 (because we all know that there are at least 10 ways to do the same thing in Mathematica)

```
A = {a, b, c}
B = {0, 1, 0}
MapIndexed[If[#1 == 1, A[[First[#2]]], Nothing] &, B]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

In spirit of @Nasser *"you can do anything 10 ways with Mathematica"*:

```
l1 = {a, b, c};
l2 = {0, 1, 0};
Reap[Sow @@@ Thread[{l1, l2}], 1, #2[[1]] &][[2]]
```

yields {b}